# Build custom state object with failed promises in React Native using axios within a custom Hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, axios, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a custom state within a custom Hook (RN init, not expo)
This state is

```
interface ResponseState {
    api1: {
        error: boolean;
        errorMsg?: string;
        data?: DataResponse; // interfaces/blablabla
    };
    api2: {
        error: boolean;
        errorMsg?: string;
        data?: DataResponse; // interfaces/blablabla
    };
}

...

const [myData, setMyData] = useState<ResponseState>({
    api1: {
        error: false,
        errorMsg: '',
    },
    api2: {
        error: false,
        errorMsg: '',
    }
});
```

Then, I try to work with Promise.all and build state accordingly in case some endpoint fails. I don't want to remove failed ones from the final state

The following code works (in case all promises work fine)

```
const p1 = MyAxios.get<ResponseState>("/404api1");
const p2 = MyAxios.get<ResponseState>("/api2");
await Promise.all([p1, p2])
    .then(function (res) {
        setMyData({
            api1: { error: false, datos: res[0].data },
            api2: { error: false, datos: res[1].data },
        })
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.error('====!!!!!err', err);
    });
```

But... How should I build my state in case some of the promises fail? And get its corresponding error message for each one that failed... 404, maybe other gives 500, and so. I have around 15 endpoints in different urls, domains to manage in this hook

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), you can use [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) which doesn't immediately reject if one of the promises rejects, rather it stores that rejection in the array. Similarly to `Promise.all`, this function will return an array of values, but the values will instead be objects of the structure `{status: 'fulfilled', value: '<val>'}` for a resolved promise, and `{status: 'rejected', reason: '<error msg>'}` for a rejected promise. You can then set your data accordingly

Answer (score -1):

`Promise.all` is fail-fast, i.e. it will reject immediately if any of the promises rejects.

Use [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) if you want to execute all promises and receive an array with the outcomes.

Comment: Promise.allSettled gives me unknown function in React Native logs

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware it's not supported in RN - you can use a polyfill, though: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.allsettled